# Install odoo requirments

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, python-ldap

I am trying to learn `odoo` but when I try to install requirements from requirement.txt file  using the command `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt` I get the following error:

```sh
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-7VpR4f/python-ldap/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-rosrtv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-7VpR4f/python-ldap/
```

so please can any one help me ?!

Comment: You need to install some libraries to be able to compile python modules, try `sudo apt install build-essential python3-dev libxslt-dev libzip-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hossam aboouf

Installation `Odoo` with `python3`:

> `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`
>     `sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt`
>  
>     `sudo apt install python3-setuptools`
>     `sudo apt install python3-dev`

If you face any other library package than execute this `cmd`:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libffi-dev
```